# File Upload hangs with Multer in Krakenjs application

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, kraken.js, multer

I am using multer (^0.1.6) in a Nodejs Kraken application to upload a file. I looked at the multer documentation on npm and it seemed it's pretty straightforward to use this module for file upload.

But I have been facing issues while uploading file on my local machine. Interestingly, I notice the file gets uploaded but my server hangs and the control never goes to the next middleware in the application which is responsible for rendering the next page.

I also noticed that when the server is hung, it tried to upload the file again and finally times out saying "No data received". As a result of multer's retry, I see two copies of same file uploaded.

Here is my kraken application code using multer module:

### index.js (root leve index.js at same level as package.json)

```
...
.....
app = module.exports = express();
app.use(kraken(options));

app = module.exports = express();
app.use(kraken(options));
app.on('start', function () {
console.log('Application ready to serve requests.');
console.log('Environment: %s', app.kraken.get('env:env'));
});

   app.use(multer({
    dest: '/Users/abc/temp/fileuploads',
    limits: {
        fieldNameSize: 500,
        files: 2,
        fields: 5
    },
    rename: function (fieldname, filename) {
        return fieldname + filename + Date.now();
    },
    onFileUploadStart: function (file) {
        console.log('Upload starting for filename: ' + file.originalname);
    },
    onFileUploadData: function (file, data) {
        console.log(data.length + ' of ' + file.fieldname + ' arrived')
    },
    onParseStart: function () {
        console.log('Form parsing started at: ', new Date())
    },
    onParseEnd: function (req, next) {
        console.log('Form parsing completed at: ', new Date());
        next();
    },
    onFileUploadComplete: function (file) {
        console.log(file.fieldname + ' uploaded to  ' + file.path);
    },
    onFileSizeLimit: function (file) {
        console.log('Failed: ', file.originalname)
        fs.unlink('./' + file.path) // delete the partially written file
    },
    onFilesLimit: function () {
        console.log('Crossed file limit!')
    },
    onFieldsLimit: function () {
        console.log('Crossed fields limit!')
    },
    onPartsLimit: function () {
        console.log('Crossed parts limit!')
    },
    onError: function(error, next) {
        console.log("Error occurred while uploading the file!!");
        next(error);
    }
    }));

index.js (under controllers directory of Kraken application)
-------------------------------------------------------------

    router.post('/upload', function (req, res) {

            console.log("File Uploaded");

            model.status = "File Uploaded!!";

            var body = req.body;
            console.log("File attributes: " + JSON.stringify(body));

            var files = req.files;
            console.log("Files: " + JSON.stringify(files));


            res.render('uploadfile/datauploadform', model);

        });
```

Here are the application logs after I start uploading the file (notice multer tried to upload same file twice before timing out):

`Form parsing started at:  Sat Jan 10 2015 01:29:45 GMT-0800 (PST)
Upload starting for filename: HelloNashorn.js
35 of file arrived
file uploaded to  /Users/abc/temp/fileuploads/fileHelloNashorn1420882185450.js
Form parsing completed at:  Sat Jan 10 2015 01:29:45 GMT-0800 (PST)`

`Form parsing started at:  Sat Jan 10 2015 01:31:45 GMT-0800 (PST)
Upload starting for filename: HelloNashorn.js
35 of file arrived
file uploaded to  /Users/abc/temp/fileuploads/fileHelloNashorn1420882305450.js
Form parsing completed at:  Sat Jan 10 2015 01:31:45 GMT-0800 (PST)`

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Are you sure it is multer that is parsing twice?  Kraken has formidable in it already for processing multipart forms and that may be one of the uploads. I'm taking a look at it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kraken uses [meddleware](https://github.com/krakenjs/meddleware) to handle any middleware that needs to be loaded.  That may be part of the problem since you're adding the multer middlware "manually."  But are you using multer because you want some of its features or are you just trying to get a file uploaded?  If it's the latter you can forget multer and just do the following.

In your html page do this (assuming you're using [dustjs](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs) for your templates):

```
<form method="POST" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="myfile" />
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{_csrf}" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Then in your controller do this:

```
router.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
    fs.rename(req.files['myfile'].path, './' + req.files['myfile'].name, function(err) {
        res.render('index', model);
    });
});
```

The above code will just dump the file in the root application directory, which you won't want, so adjust as needed.

Comment: Thanks HeadCode! Your answer did help me in finding solution to the above problem so I have accepted your answer. I wanted to use multer because I wanted use all the events provided by multer and better control file upload. I was able to resolve multer issue and just posted my solution below.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I was able to make Multer work and I was able to upload file without hanging my application. The reason I wanted to use multer because it provides a rich set of events which can give you better control over your file uploads.

This is what I had to do to make Multer work with Kraken. Since Kraken registers it's middleware through a module called meddleware so I had to register Multer as meddleware inside config/config.json file of Kraken app. While configuring Multer, I had to ensure that the priority of Multer is less the priority of Router so that my Multer middleware could be registered before router gets registered.

Multer provides an event called onParseEnd which is triggered when form parsing is completed. As per Multer documentation on npm, make sure you call next() in your listener or your request will be left hanging.

My source code for file upload with Multer and Kraken is here: https://github.com/prabhash1785/NodeJS/tree/master/KrakenApps/fileuploadwithmulter

Couple of other notes:

- If you just want to upload a file without worrying about Multer Event
  features then you don't have to use Multer. Express/Kraken has built
  in support for file upload (multipart/form-data). The uploaded file
  could be accessed in controller by using req.files.[file_name].path
  [where, file_name is your name of file defined in your template]
- Second if you want to upload/sftp your files to a remote storage server (server other than where your Node application is deployed)
  then for this consider using node modules like ssh2/sftp-upload/scp2.
  I have few code samples for file upload/sftp using these modules
  here: https://github.com/prabhash1785/NodeJS/tree/master/fileupload